# mailgun send template email via SMTP

Tags: mailgun

I've created a HTML template on mailgun site. It work fine when I call the API restful.

So, I need use the template via SMTP.

My question: is possible to add headers on SMTP to use the template?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Mailgun templates are only available through their web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the template name to use by using the `X-Mailgun-Template-Name` header and setting the name of your template as the value.

The template variables / placeholders you can set as a JSON string using the `X-Mailgun-Template-Variables` header.

For example if you use PHP `SwiftMailer` you can do the following:

```php
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Template-Name', 'mytemplate');
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Template-Variables', \json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
```

You can find the name of your template in the Mailgun backend under `Sending` => `Templates`.